# Question limit?

Tags: discussion, questions

Is it my mistake that people were not able to answer questions that I ask, or they do not bother to answer some petty questions?
 I sent a request to enable my question limit, according to the admins, the questions need to be helpful to others in the community, which I disagree from, as many questions are problems which happen in a rare chance and others do not find, still people answer those questions.

In a fit to ask one question I even deleted the previous questions, because even if I delete them, the problem had been solved so I couldn't just put a new question replacing the old one, only to find that even after deleting, I couldn't ask questions.

In a list of the first fifty questions, you could see that 38 of them aren't answered, that is 76% questions haven't been answered which are posted until now. The admins, can see themselves that although there isn't a question that (according to them) aren't worthy to be shown here, I have answered many questions.

I really had a bad experience here in 2013, when the admins deleted, and reverted the posts, votes and comments from a fellow friend of mine who used superuser after I told him to, if he had any problem on his computer, that there are many people who would solve any problem. But I don't want to address that thing here.

I just want to request the moderators or the administrators to open my question limit, so that I can be able to ask questions here.

Answer (score 5):

[This is covered in the help pages](https://superuser.com/help/question-bans)

Fact is there's no manual way for a moderator to undo a question ban.
You have 12 deleted questions (and from a quick look through, I can't really see anything that can be salvaged) and 2 non deleted questions *all of which are zero score*. Many of these are abandoned (and as such deleted automatically) or self deleted.

This is the system working more or less as designed and *no human moderator* was involved in this decision.

Typically I go through questions and say "Hey, you should fix these questions" - though nothing really comes to mind from your list.

Comment: That's why I asked here, as I asked an admin back in 2013, but he denied to do it then, but now I was going to start using this site again which I abandoned for what they did to me in 2013, and I had a problem in my PC too, that's why. There must be a way to do it, please why doesn't any admin help. I always answer questions here, but what can I do if the questions I ask are so petty, or no one bothers to answer them. Please ask some administrator, of he can do anything.

Comment: And also as these questions are very old, and most of them were solved by my end, so I can't even edit then. Even the two posted already, I can't change the question wholly to a new one.

Comment: "Stack Exchange cannot lift question bans by request."  Says so right there on the link. There's nothing really that can be done for you by a mod.

Comment: Is there anything I can do, I am wondering if any administrator could do anything. Are admins and mods same or different?

Comment: "Is there anything I can do" - read the link right on top of my answer. While we do refer some stuff over to community managers, this is a clear cut case which the rules cover. Once again, *your suspension is due to an automated system working as designed* and this is something that is covered in the help pages.

Comment: Alright I admit, that it is automatic, but seriously it says that the ban will be lifted when your positive contribution outweighs the negative questions, or whatever, so I wonder how much contribution I need, to get the ban uplifted. And there seems to be no time limit to it. Come on there must be some way, or then shouldn't this thing be fixed or it's policies revised, with getting the website updated. I think this could be done.

Comment: You're making it sound like the system is *broken*. Yes, there is no time limit. Else someone would just go away for X time, come back and ask poor questions. How much contributions is kept vague on purpose, once again, to reduce the chance of gaming the system. Once again *all this is intentional*.

Comment: But you can see how much I have contributed, I have 440 reputation only in answers, and still isn't this enough, I am not always asking questions. Most of the time I always answer them. I am a BCA student, so only some petty things bother me sometimes, or some in case are unanswerable. Of you think that I an doing this on purpose then I an so sorry. But you could always see how much I have contributed.

Comment: @Hunter Posting comments as answers is not going to help you get out of your question ban.

Comment: Sorry, but I have deleted it, the problem is that I am using an android phone, and I am using desktop version of the site, and instead of scrolling sideways, I scroll downwards like in android, and so have pushed the answer button, and didn't see it. That's why I thought why my written comment didn't show up and I had to retype the whole comment.

Comment: Your answers does nothing towards your ability to ask questions you can be bared from submitting answers also...Stop blaming your question ban on other people, you asked and deleted 12 questions, that action alone likely is 50% of the reason your question banned right now